# How do I find the maximum value of the force between two blocks?

Tags: vectors, physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is as follows:

> In the figure from below there are two blocks, one over another. The
>   system is at rest. The horizontal surface is frictionless and the
>   coefficient of static friction is $0.45$ Find the maximum value of $F$
>   in $N$ such as the blocks will not slide between them. (You may use
>   $g=10\frac{m}{s^{2}}$)

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&58\,N\\
2.&42\,N\\
3.&30\,N\\
4.&25\,N\\
5.&10\,N\\
\end{array}$

In my attempt to solve this problem I thought that:

For the lighter block:

$F-mg\times \mu_{s}=0$

$F= 5\times 10 \left(0.45\right)=22.5\,N$

But this ain't the case. I don't know how to relate this with what is happening in the block from below.

The answer supposedly is $30\,N$. But I have no idea how to get there. Can somebody offer some help here please?.

Comment: You forgot to multiply by $g$. But indeed $5\cdot 10 \cdot 0.45 = 22.5$, which is not among the answers...

Comment: @MattiP. I corrected that error and yet the answer still doesn't convince me as I'm confused at what's happening to the other block?, can I ignore that fact so easily?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum that can be applied to the lower block is $mg\mu_s=22.5N$. Thus the acceleration of the lower block would be $22.5/15=1.5m/s^2$

So for the blocks to not slide between them, the upper block can move at maximum $1.5m/^2$ acceleration. Which means $$F=mg\mu_s+m\times 1.5=30N$$

Answer (score 0):

Your $\ 22.5\ N\ $ is the maximum horizontal force that can be transferred by friction from the $\ 5 kg\ $ block to the $\ 25\ kg\ $ block without any slippage occurring.  Subject to that horizontal force the lower block will accelerate at $\ a=\frac{22.5}{15}\ m/s^2\ $.  For the $\ 5\ kg\ $ block to accelerate at the same rate, the *nett* horizontal force on it, which is $\ F-22.5\ N\ $, must be $\ \frac{5\times 22.5}{15}=7.5 N\ $.  Therefore $\ F=22.5+7.5=30\ N\ $.

Comment: The block in the bottom is $15\,kg$ but I don't get the idea of where does it come the equation $F-22.5=7.5$?. Do you imply that the $F$ which I thought that is pulling forward is in fact going backwards?. Because of this reason I requested the addition of a FBD so I can understand exactly what's going on.

Comment: If the $\ 5 kg\ $ block exerts a force of $\ 22.5\ N\ $ horizontally to the right on the  $\ 15\ kg\ $ block, then by Newton's third law, the $\ 15\ kg\ $ block must exert an opposite force of equal magnitude—that is, a force of $\ 22.5\ N\ $ horizontally to the left—on the $\ 5\ kg\ $ block.

Comment: Thus, the *nett* force acting on the $\ 5\ kg\ $ is the vector sum of the force of magnitude $\ F\ $ acting towards the right and the reaction force of $\ 22.5\ N\ $ acting towards the left.  Thus, if $\ \mathbf{i}\ $ is a unit vector directed horizontally to the right, then the nett force acting on the $\ 5\ kg\ $ block is $\ (F-22.5)\mathbf{i}\ $.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt:

Small body :$m$; Big body : $3m$.

1) Both are moving with the same acceleration $a$:

Only an external force  $F$ is acting on the system :

1) $F=ma +3ma=4ma$;

2) Maximal force due to friction  pulling body $3m$ with maximal acceleration $a_m$:

$3ma_m=\mu m g$;

$a_m= (1/3)\mu g$;

3) $F_m=4ma_m=$

$4 (5)(1/3)(0.45)10 [N];$

$F=20\cdot 1,5 [N] =30 [N]$.

Comment: The force $F$ is acting by a rope only (in the sense that it can be seen physically connected to it and not the one in the bottom) to the **upper** block. But **why** you do the analysis as if that force is also acting on the block from the **bottom**? What's the **justification** for summing both forces? Can you explain this part please?

Comment: Chris.Assume no friction between small and big block.The big block remains in place and the small one slides on top of it. Then: What pulls the big block. It is the frictional force between the two.The big one 'wants' to remain in place (inertia) ,  the small blick exerts an outside (outside of the big block ) pull on it. Your thoughts?

Comment: Does it mean should I treat the big block as if were a static equilibrium?. In other words equating the acting forces on that block to zero?. The frictional force is pointing where?. To the left?. Or for the block on the bottom the frictional force is pointing to the right?.

Comment: In your example, where's the inertia?. On me or in the train?. I'm getting the idea that's on me. I'm understanding that for me, the force which accelerates me forward is the frictional force. Which normally is against the motion, in this case is acting on my favor, making me going in the same direction of the train, is this logic correct?.

Comment: Yes!! We need friction to walk. Ice skating. Can you move forward by 'walking'? One more thing.As small block acts on big: Friction pulls the big one forward.OK. Same friction pulls the small one backward, means external force on small 1) Outside force -minus friction.What effect? If you apply  F to small body , no friction the small one would be accelerating faster, with friction (no relative movement) the frictional pull backward slows down the small one, but the we consider now the total mass (m +3m) times a =F , a bigger mass with a smaller a. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

For the small body

$$
F -\mu m_1 g = m_1 a
$$

for the large body

$$
\mu m_1 g = m_2 a
$$

(The two bodies move at the same acceleration)

then

$$
\frac{1}{m_1}\left(F-\mu m_1 g\right) = \frac{1}{m_2}\mu m_1 g
$$

Comment: Thanks buddy but **Why** in your second equation the frictional force is treated as if it would be going in  the right direction. Can you explain what's the origin of the second equation?. The only thing that makes sense to me is $m_{2}a-f_{s}=0$ but why equate it to zero. It looks as if I'm treating the second object as if it were on equilibrium. Can you explain this part **clearer** please?.

Comment: Principle of action-reaction at the contact between the two bodies.

Comment: Does it mean that it should be treated as if it were an equilibrium? In other words the sum of forces equal to zero? I mean for the second object. Is this logic correct?.

Comment: The two bodies are supposed to be at the same acceleration.

Comment: In other words, the frictional force going in the same direction as the object which is moving below?. Frictional force is against the motion, in this case is in favor the motion.

Comment: The frictional force is considered as an internal (cancelled) force. Thus adding the two equations we get at $F = (m_1+m_2) a$